# Best practice to pass an array from one php page to a different javascript page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm using AJAX to send a request to another php page where it returns the result of a query. I was calling it through xmlhttprequest to javascript to get the contents of that php page, but since i was mixing presentation logic "e.g. echo blah blah" with actual code logic I wanted to find a way where I could leave the php logic with my query alone, store the result on an array, and through ajax pass it down to my js code to use in a function.

I'm trying to populate a drop down list with the contents of this array. I've tried json encode but I'm not having any luck.

Here's code for the php page requested:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


$con = mysqli_connect('*******','********','******','****');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$j = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['j']);

mysqli_select_db($con,"4h");
$sql="SELECT nombreClub FROM club4h WHERE oficinaLoc LIKE '%".$j."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $response[] = $row;
}

file_put_contents('getnombre.php',json_encode($response));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my js function:

```
function loadDoc(url, cfunc, sel){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            cfunc(xhttp);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", url +sel, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function selClub(xhttp) {
    document.getElementById("nombreClub").style.display = "inline";
    var optData = <?php file_get_contents('getnombre.php'); ?>;
    var newClub = document.getElementById("addClub");
    newClub.type = "text";
    document.getElementById("addOption").style.display = "inline";
            $("#addOption").click(function(){
            $("#nombreClub").append('<option value="' + $("#addClub").val() + '">' + $("#addClub").val() + '</option>');
            $("#nombreClub").last().focus;
            });
}
```

I call it through an onchange event when an user clicks a previous drop down list so this drop down list gets populated with options specific for the previous list. I know how to add the options to the list, I'm just having trouble getting the data from the php page to js without having to do something like this:

```
$a = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['a']);

mysqli_select_db($con,"4h");
$sql="SELECT nombre FROM personal4h WHERE unidadProg LIKE '%".$a."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo '<select name="agenteExt" id="agenteExt">
    <option value="">Seleccione Agente</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value =" . $row['nombre'] . ">" . htmlentities($row['nombre']) . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use AJAX, JSON to send dropdown options' array.

Comment: Would returning the database query results back as a [JSON file from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script) be a suitable  alternative  to creating "getnombre.php" as a buffer? (Noting the file should really be called "getnombre.json")

Comment: What do you mean @Traktor53?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt to explain how to do this...

### PHP Query Page

Query your data and return it as JSON. PHP has a `json_encode()` function to do this.

```
// ...your code to query database which should make an array like this
$query_results = array(
    array('agent'=>'Agent 1'),
    array('agent'=>'Agent 2'),
    array('agent'=>'Agent 3')
);

return json_encode($query_results);
```

### HTML Page should have your select

```
<select name="agenteExt" id="agenteExt"></select>
```

### JavaScript

A function to get data via AJAX

```
function loadDoc(url, callback){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            if( callback ) callback(xhttp)
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The function to get the data to fill your `html`

```
function fillOptions(){
    loadDoc('your-query-page.php', function(xhttp){

        // parse the JSON data into a JavaScript object
        var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

        // get the `<select>` element
        var el = document.getElementById('agenteExt');

        var html = '<option>Make a selection</option>';

        // loop through data and create each `<option>` for the select
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            html += '<option value="'+data[i].agent+'">'+data[i].agent+'</option>'
        }

        // update the select with the new options
        el.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally made it work echoing the variable encoded as json from the php page. I don't know why but when i saved the array to the variable like `$response = $row` it would return a json encoded double array and I could only get the first value out of it iterating with a for loop because it was `$response[0][0]`, the other values would be undefined. I modified it to be `$response = $row["nombreClub"];` and then the JSON parse worked and I could iterate for it. Your help is appreciated!